# How to program relative path from string in Java

Tags: java, shell, path

I have the following problem. I am writing a program that imitates Windows Command prompt. For example user enters: `cd C:\\Intel` and in my code I solve it like this:

```
setCurrentPath(Paths.get(string));
```

where `setCurrentPath` is a method which sets the current path to the one which is entered (string). My problem is that, how can I set new path if the entered path is relative. For example, if I am currently in `C:\\Intel` and user wants to go to `C:\\Intel\\Logs` and enters: `cd Logs` (instead of `C:\\Intel\\Logs`). I suppose there are some methods build in Java which can help me out but I am learning Java only a few months so I am unaware of them. Be aware that I threat path as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test if path from user is absolute or not and based on result either set it directly, or use [`Path.resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-).

DEMO:

```
Path currentPath = Paths.get("C:\\projects\\project1");
String pathFromUser = "..\\project2";

Path userPath = Paths.get(pathFromUser);

if (userPath.isAbsolute()){
    currentPath = userPath;
}else{//is relative
    currentPath = currentPath.resolve(userPath).normalize();
}

System.out.println(currentPath);
```

Output: `C:\projects\project2`

Comment: Should this work with: cd .. ? because in my code it simply goes deeper. For example, if I am in C:\Intel\Logs and write cd .. it goes to: C\Intel\Logs\..

Comment: Interesting. It works fine on my Windows machine. Maybe try with different path separator, so instead of ``\`` use `/`. It seems to be working here: https://ideone.com/efe1ur

Comment: It works, I was experimenting with code and deleted .normalize(). Now when I get it back it works as it should. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isAbsolute()` method to check the input and then use the `resolvePath` if the `isAbsolute()` method returns false.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#isAbsolute()

The reason why you have to check if the path is absolute first is described below for the resolve method:

```
Path resolve(Path other)
```

> Resolve the given path against this path. If the other parameter is an
>   absolute path then this method trivially returns other. If other is an
>   empty path then this method trivially returns this path. Otherwise
>   this method considers this path to be a directory and resolves the
>   given path against this path. In the simplest case, the given path
>   does not have a root component, in which case this method joins the
>   given path to this path and returns a resulting path that ends with
>   the given path. Where the given path has a root component then
>   resolution is highly implementation dependent and therefore
>   unspecified.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)